# How can i drop or ignore "syn" packets for opening connection in perl socket programing over linux that use listen() function?

Tags: linux, perl, sockets

I need a way to ignore connection requests (e.g syn req) for my server that listens via "listen()" funcion using perl socket programing.

I realized that "listen()" listens to the socket and response imidiately to syn request with syn-ack.

delay the syn-ack response to the request is also countable.

Thanks !

Comment: If you want to ignore connection requests, why not just not `listen()`?  Or you could use a firewall to block requests to that port

Comment: Maybe explain what the *real* problem is that you are trying to solve. A server accepting connections cannot be the problem ,right?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is as easy as you think, because the `listen()` function works at a higher level than the TCP/IP packet stream. It opens a socket, tells the OS to accept incoming connections.

It's therefore the OS that's handling the `SYN` packets first, and is why firewalls are often used to deal with this problem. You *might* be able to do something involving generating your own packets (I haven't tried, so I'm not going to recommend anything) and manually 'handling' the connection. (You'd almost certainly need to be operating as a privileged user to do this too).

But I would have to ask - why do you want to do this?

I mean `SYN` is an essential part of the 3-way handshake of setting up a TCP/IP session. If you *don't* want a TCP/IP session to be established, then why open a port in the first place?

I would suggest that if it's for filtering of incoming traffic, then the tool for the job is a firewall like `iptables`.

Comment: I need this option in order to simulate situation where a "connect timeout" is happening in the client. Connect timeout in the client  is where the client sent a connection request (syn) and the connection is not established immediately , e.g the server do not response with a syn-ack . I addition,  i must simulate this when the server is up and i prefer using "internal" software solution for this rather using external tools that preventing the packet from entering the machine (e.g iptables).

Thanks !

Comment: That is exactly my scenario. I currently connect to an address from a reserved IPv4 block and the connection is dropped by the network firewall currently but opening a dropping network service on localhost would be more stable. @idan, what solution did you use eventually?